# Reading partitioned parquet files with Apache Beam and Python SDK

Tags: python, apache-beam, parquet

I have parquet files partitioned by `iso_week` and need to read all the data as a `PCollection` with `Apache Beam` and the `Python SDK`.

Partitioned Parquet Files Structure

```
data_to_read/
├─ iso_week=2023-W40/
│  ├─ 12343435.parquet
├─ iso_week=2023-W41/
│  ├─ 1231243254.parquet
```

I tried to use the global pattern `*` as suggested in the [documentation](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.55.0/apache_beam.io.parquetio.html#apache_beam.io.parquetio.ReadFromParquet):

```
pipeline | "ReadData" >> beam.io.ReadFromParquet("data_to_read/*")
```

But I get the Error that the path doesn't contain any parquet file.

Is there a way to read partitioned parquet files in Apache Beam?

Comment: I just referenced the document and probably does not matter but can you try `pipeline | "ReadData" >> beam.io.ReadFromParquet("data_to_read*")` instead ?

Comment: I tried but I got the same error

Comment: Can you try "data_to_read/**"

Comment: @XQHu it works but I lost the partitions data.

Comment: you probably can create a dict that contains the partition data, which you can look up and use this inside the beam pipeline.